# Ignoring html entities when using javascript regex replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, replace

I'm trying to wrap 'a to z', '&', number characters and numbers with a `<span>` tag in a list that contains a mix of Latin and Korean text like so (simplified version):

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  var replaced_text = $(this).html().replace(/([a-zA-Z ])/g, '<span>$&</span>');
  $(this).html(replaced_text)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>&lt;서베이 WRM&gt;, 2019</li>
  <li>가나APAP다라 2018</li>
  <li>마바사아APAP 20&nbsp;17</li>
  <li>WKM마2바사아 20&nbsp;17</li>
</ul>
```

But currently it is also replacing the letters in html entities such as `&nbsp; &gt; &lt;`, for example  `&lt;` becomes `&<span>l</span><span>t</span>;` and so on.

So as per my title, how can i wrap those characters by using the replace function while avoiding html entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be easier to retrieve the `textContent` (or `.text()`, if you have to use the jQuery method) instead, which parses the entities to the displayed characters:

```js
$('li').each(function() {
  var replaced_text = $(this).text().replace(/([a-zA-Z ])/g, '<span>$&</span>');
  $(this).html(replaced_text)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>&lt;서베이 WRM&gt;, 2019</li>
  <li>가나APAP다라 2018</li>
  <li>마바사아APAP 20&nbsp;17</li>
  <li>WKM마2바사아 20&nbsp;17</li>
</ul>
```